No se puede resolver 'Microsoft.NET.ILLink.Tasks (>= 8.0.5)'
Hoy he arrancado mi proyecto de MAUI como hago siempre y al compilar me muestra este error:
Gravedad  Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido    Detalles
Error  NU1100  No se puede resolver 'Microsoft.NET.ILLink.Tasks (>= 8.0.5)' para 'net8.0-ios17.2/maccatalyst-x64'. PackageSourceMapping está habilitado. No se tuvieron en cuenta los siguientes orígenes: C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org. eversia C:\Users\sergiol\OneDrive - S.A\Documentos\source\repos\.csproj    1
Creo recordar que actualicé Visual Studio 2022 hace unos días. Pero no se por qué tengo este problema.
He buscado por la red pero no encuentro ninguna solución que yo puedan entender.
Agradecería muchísimo la ayuda. Un saludo.
